# About a determinant identity.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ is any matrix and $B$ is a rank $2$ matrix of the same dimension then it follows that for any real $t$,

$det(A -B) = [1-\partial_p + \frac{1}{2}\partial_p^2 ]det(A + pB) \vert _{p=0}$

I guess this can be shown by writing $B$ as a sum of two rank $1$ matrices and then using this formula ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma ) and then doing the Sherman-Morrison for the inverse and then again doing the matrix determinant lemma. Eventually this leads to the conclusion that $det(A+tB)$ is a polynomial quadratic in $t$. And then this differential operator follows from writing the Taylor series of $det(A+tB)$ as that of a quadratic polynomial in $t$ and then setting $t=-1$

- Firstly is the argument above correct?
- Secondly are there other differential operators which can do such a similar mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler hints :

- $A\to \textrm{det}(A)$ is an alternated multilinear map if you see a matrix as the data of $n$ vectors (its columns for instance), that is, if you identify $\mathbf{M}_n(\mathbf{R})$ and $\underbrace{\mathbf{R}^n \times \ldots \times \mathbf{R}^n}_{\textrm{$n$ times}}$
- do you know of the calculate the differential of an alternated multilinear map ?
- do you you know the differential of $g\circ f$ in function of differentials of $g$ and $f$ ?

This will allow you to calculate easily the derivatives of $t\mapsto \textrm{det}(A+tB)$ (which is a polynomial function in the variable $t$) and to conclude.

Comment: So what are you trying to get at? I guess you are agreeing that my formula is correct. But I am not sure if the operator I constructed maintains real rootedness of polynomials - thats what I am trying to get at - imagine the special case where $A = zI$ - then the LHS is the characteristic polynomial for $B$ and for Hermitian (or any other class?) $B$ this has only real roots - now I would like to see this as preserving the real rooted structure of may be $det(z + pB)$ by this operator. But are there other candidate operators?

Comment: I'm giving a way to calculate all the derivatives, and not only in the case $n=2$ but for a general $n$. For your case $n=2$ you can use the bruteforce approach : expend everything and compare, but it's not elegant to compute when you can avoir doing it.